# Refresh token OpenIddict in Asp Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net, api, oauth

I'd like to add refresh token functionnality in my API, so when a user in y application call the API, if its token is still valid, it will be refresh.

I added the authorizationController, here is the code :

```
[HttpPost("~/connect/token"), Produces("application/json")]
    public IActionResult Exchange(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
    {
        if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
        {
            // Validate the user credentials.
            // Note: to mitigate brute force attacks, you SHOULD strongly consider
            // applying a key derivation function like PBKDF2 to slow down
            // the password validation process. You SHOULD also consider
            // using a time-constant comparer to prevent timing attacks.
            User user = new Models.User();
            using (var db = new UserContext())
            {
                user = db.User.Where(u => u.login == request.Username).FirstOrDefault();
                if (request.Username != user.login ||  request.Password != user.pwd)
                {
                    return Forbid(OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                }
            }

            // Create a new ClaimsIdentity holding the user identity.
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role);
            // Add a "sub" claim containing the user identifier, and attach
            // the "access_token" destination to allow OpenIddict to store it
            // in the access token, so it can be retrieved from your controllers.
            identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject,
                "71346D62-9BA5-4B6D-9ECA-755574D628D8",
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);
            identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name, user.login,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);
            // ... add other claims, if necessary.
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            // Ask OpenIddict to generate a new token and return an OAuth2 token response.
            return SignIn(principal, OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The specified grant type is not supported.");
    }
```

and my Startup.cs code :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {          

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options =>
        {              
            options.UseOpenIddict();
        });     

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;
        });


        services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
        {
            options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<UserContext>();
            options.AddMvcBinders();
            options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");
            options.AllowPasswordFlow().AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
            .SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20))
            .SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
            options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
        });

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/mylog-{Date}.txt");
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseOpenIddict();
        app.UseOAuthValidation();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        app.UseMvc();   

    }
```

The authentication and token generation are working, but not the refreshing of the token. I added `SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20))` and `SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));`

The first one is working, my token expiration equals 20 minutes, but the token is never refreshed.